PHP: Не могу получить данные $_POST из формы
Делаю сайт для конкурса. Мне нужно сделать форму обратной связи, чтобы можно оставить свои контакты и в ближайшее время связаться с человеком. Проблема уже сразу возникла, когда проверял работу сайта: при попытки внести данные в бд, они почему-то не сохраняются в переменные и не отправляются в $_POST, даже при условии, что подключение к БД успешное, и что я верно указал путь к скрипту, а также имена input'ов для передачи.
Вывод:
Подключение успешное!
Warning: Undefined array key "name" in C:\OSPanel\domains\cool-academy\php\add_fb_on_req.php on line 4

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\OSPanel\domains\cool-academy\php\add_fb_on_req.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "tel" in C:\OSPanel\domains\cool-academy\php\add_fb_on_req.php on line 6
Пустые значения

Я проверял путь, имена, метод - бесполезно. Причём на другой работе, где уже надо регистрироваться, проблем у меня не было, то есть с точки зрения сервера вопросов нет (пользуюсь open server).
Помогите срочно мне, пожалуйста, и как можно скорее, так как совсем скоро мне нужно сдать свой проект на конкурс! Буду очень благодарен!!!
HTML:
index.html
<form action="php/add_fb_on_req.php" method="post" class="feedback">
                    <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <input name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" placeholder="Email" type="email" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <input name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="+7(___)___-__-__" type="tel" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <button type="submit">
                        Отправить
                    </button>
                    <p class="desc">
                        Нажимая кнопку, я соглашаюсь с <a href="" target="_blank" class="link">Положением о персональных данных</a> и даю согласие на их обработку и хранение.
                    </p>
                </form>

PHP:
sql.php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_http_output('UTF-8');
    // mb_http_input('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');


    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $login = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'cool_academy_bd';

    $connect = new mysqli($host, $login, $password, $dbname);

    if ($connect->connect_error) {
        die("Ошибка подключения: " . $connect->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo "Подключение успешное!";
    }
?>

add_fb_on_req.php
<?php
    include 'sql.php';
    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];

    if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST)) { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `feedback` (`name`, `email`, `tel`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$tel')";

        if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            header("location: ../feedback.html");
        } else {
            echo "Ошибка: " . $connect->error;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Пустые значения";
    }

    $connect->close();
?>


Открой в браузере инструменты разработчика, и на вкладке Network убедись что когда пользоавтель нажимает "Отправить", то запрос отправляется методом POST и в теле запроса присутствуют параметры name, email и tel. Если этого нет, ошибку надо искать в HTML разметке. Если присутствует, значит ошибка может быть в настройках сервера (¿не принимает POST запросы?). В коде ошибок на первый взгляд нет.

Я бы за такой код поставил кол, даже рабочий. Так что отправлять его на конкурс не вижу смысла.

Если у вас подключение скрипта add_fb_on_req.php происходит в том же скрипте где выводится форма, или же это один и тот же скрипт, то
ваша ошибка заключается в том, что Вы обращаетесь к конкретным элементам массива $_POST ДО проверки на то, что данные значения Вам пришли
<?php
    ...    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    
    if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST)) {
       ...
    }
    ...
?>

Все что Вам нужно, для того чтобы эта ошибка исчезла, это перенести назначение переменных из $_POST внутрь if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST)) { и добавить проверки на то, что ключи внутри массива $_POST из которых Вы берете значения для переменных - существуют.
<?php
    include 'sql.php';

    if (!empty($_POST) && 
         isset($_POST) && 
         isset($_POST['name']) && 
         isset($_POST['email']) && 
         isset($_POST['tel']) ) { 
    
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `feedback` (`name`, `email`, `tel`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$tel')";

        if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            header("location: ../feedback.html");
        } else {
            echo "Ошибка: " . $connect->error;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Пустые значения";
    }

    $connect->close();
?>


Мне интересно, кто из вас не понял вопроса - вы сами или chatgpt? Судя по формулировкам, скорее второе. Но в любом случае это не ответ на вопрос, а бессмысленное сотрясение воздуха .

"Иван Васильевич, Вы когда говорите, такое ощущение что.. бредите"
